# Session sharing in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, session

Consider the following scenario:

1. There are 2 pages in a server, namely: parent.php and child.php
2. parent.php sets a session containing highly-secretive information
3. parent.php then calls child.php via Ajax then process whatever information is received

**The enigma:** 
child.php needs to have the same session state as parent.php in order to give the information parent.php requested.

Is this possible?

Comment: You mean, via Ajax in the browser? If the two pages are on the same domain, in the same directory, the session will always be carried over automatically.

Comment: This should happen transparently. You don't even need to do anything.

Comment: I'm stupid. That I now know.

Comment: Only a smart man actually knows he's stupid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you call `session_start()` at the top of each script, both scripts are on the same domain, and the session cookie isn't confined to a subdirectory, the variables you set in `$_SESSION` on the first request will still exist in the second.

Comment: Don't they have different instances because of the Ajax call in between them? What if the first page is in http://www.myserver.com/dir1/parent.php and the other one is in http://www.myserver.com/dir2/subdir/parent.php?

Comment: As long as they meet the requirements above, they share a session regardless of whether the request is made via AJAX or not, and whether they are consecutive or not. Variables stored in the session persist for the lifetime of the session unless explicitly deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are usually assigned through cookies being set and recognized. GET variables are also used sometimes, but is considered an elevated security threat, as the GET variable is visible in the URL.

PHP can be set to a certain level of strictness when it comes to when to re-use an existing session. You can, for example, fiddle with:

- cookie lifetime
- cookie domain settings
- cookie path
- if the IP needs to be the same every time
- if the user agent needs to be the same every time

The default settings are not very strict.

When all conditions are met, PHP will automatically re-use the existing session when session_start() is called.

Comment: Can you give an example of the usual settings to make this possible? Right now my default setting is cookie_path='/' and cookie_domain=''